# Does recursion in Excel give a wrong result on AMD processors?

Tags: excel, recursion

I try to use recursion in Excel, and just have changed my laptop from Intel to AMD, and saw a very strange issue.

Enable iterating computing with the maximum limit of 100 iterations
Try to compute, for example in cell A1 formula `=A1+1`
On my AMD laptop I've got `700` (!) instead of `100` on Intel (tried on several PCs). I couldn't tried this on another AMD PC - there is no any near. I tried to turn off multiflow calculation (only 1 core) - the same result - 700.

This issue appears only in case of constants in a formula. If we operate with links we get the same result as on Intel.

What is this could be?

Comment: re-installing ms office gave the same results? >> Microsoft care center | To play safe >> upload the (700!) file to office 365 and test (should get 100). Then, (from office 365) open in desktop.. (share what you get).   | afaik, there is no implementable recursion function in excel, just a repeated operations (a manually built for-loop).

Comment: I rebooted the PC and the problem has gone. Now I have doubt about was I drunk or it was a roamed error :D

Comment: glad it solves.. ( :